# How to 'freeze' redux state during a route change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My app uses react-router, redux, react-redux. Lets say I'm currently looking at `/about` route which renders the `AboutPage` component. Now I want to navigate to `/news`. Right now, when the route change happens the new component mounts, which fires off async actions to fetch the data. While that data is being fetched I am looking at the `NewsPage` component but with loading spinners.

What I'm trying to do is **stay** on the `AboutPage` component while all that data fetching is happening. I have successfully implemented the data fetching during react-router's `onEnter` hook. The problem is that, if `AboutPage` happens to use any of the same redux state as `NewsPage`, you'll see rendering changes while the data is being fetched and updated.

What I'd like is to somehow 'freeze' the current route while actions/state-changes are happening behind the scenes, and then render the new route component when thats ready (in the meantime users will see loading feedback via https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress).

So either I need to completely unsubscribe the current route component from state changes or otherwise lock stuff in. Not sure if redux even exposes what I need but curious if others have solved this.

Comment: you can play around with [`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) to reject re-rendering.

Comment: Oh right, that may work nicely. I can probably add a HOC somewhere in my chain that rejects re-renders while the 'loader' is busy.